# Date() shows wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using this library for a calendar: https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar

And I try to get the users current date and time, to display the correct date in calendar.

But when I try to do `print("Date: \(Date())")` I get this output:

> 2019-11-19 14:32:03 +0000

But if this was correct, it should be like this:

> 2019-11-19 15:32:03 +0000

(I live in Norway). So it give me 1 hour wrong.

Any tips on what to do?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46890038/swift-calendar-class-returning-wrong-date-for-weekday

Comment: You have to set your timezone.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699671/how-to-change-time-and-timezone-in-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date):

> A Date is independent of a particular calendar or time zone. To
> represent a Date to a user, you must interpret it in the context of a
> Calendar.

You need the help of `Calendar`:

```swift
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let currentDate = Date()
print(calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: currentDate))
```

the output will be:

```
calendar: gregorian (fixed) timeZone: Europe/Bratislava (current) era: 1 year: 2019 
month: 11 day: 19 hour: 15 minute: 47 second: 14 nanosecond: 285109996 weekday: 3 weekdayOrdinal: 3 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 4 weekOfYear: 47 yearForWeekOfYear: 2019 isLeapMonth: false
```

So you could then access your `calendar`'s components like `hour`, `minute` etc.

## UPDATE:

@Camile answered in comments to their question using `DateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate)
```

will give you

```
2019-11-19 16:38:03:+0100
```

Comment: How can I then store it in this format: `2019-11-19 15:32:03 +0000` ?

Comment: I tried this; https://pastebin.com/GH9BEeRx - And it seems to work.

Comment: @Camile check please that dateFormat string for timezone `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"`

Comment: An extra; How can I convert the output back to a `Date()`?

Comment: @Camile `let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate)
let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedDate)` you will get again timeZone independent result: `2019-11-19 16:29:55 +0000`, see the first paragraph of the answer

Comment: Having some issues, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938683/convert-from-string-to-date-with-current-timezone

Comment: @Camile `Date` is timezone independent. the answer from Leo is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285#28347285

Comment: Yea, I still don't get how to use it to save current time and date as Date().