# Convert from string to Date with current timezone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using these lines of code to convert Date and time, to the current time zone:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate)

print(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate))
```

The `print` output gives me:

> 2019-11-19 17:22:55:+0100

I am going to store the date in Realm, so how can I convert this back to a `Date()`?

**Edit; I tried converting it, but it doesn't work:**

```
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let currentDate = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone

        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate)
        let finalDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        print(dateString) -> Gives me output: 2019-11-19 18:09:05:+0100 - This is the correct time!
        print(finalDate!) -> Gives me output: 2019-11-19 17:09:05 +0000
```

So the `finalDate` should store the current time as a `Date()`, but it doesn't get the correct time.

Comment: If your goal is only storing a date and converting back you should use ISO8601 UTC  time   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016578/how-to-create-a-date-time-stamp-and-format-as-iso-8601-rfc-3339-utc-time-zone/28016692

Comment: @LeoDabus Why is that?

Comment: Do you need the user timezone? Otherwise just use ISO8601. Btw if you don't set your date formatter locale to en_US_POSIX your parsing might fail

Comment: Did you check the link in the comment above? Btw when displaying a date to the user you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332946/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-short-format-in-swift/28347285?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.3209#28347285

Comment: @LeoDabus I am creating a workout journal app, therefor I would like to store the date and time that the user saved the workout.

Comment: Just use the link I posted

Comment: ISO8601 when storing it and use the second one to display the date

Comment: It will be localized you just need to choose short or long format

Comment: Not sure if it's because I've been up for over 24hours now without sleep, but I really don't understand it. Can you provide code for me please in an answer?

Comment: All the code you need is posted there already

Comment: I dont understrand how to use it and store like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z` as `Date()`.

Comment: you have to store it as string or number. But again use ISO8601 format

Comment: if you just need to convert from `Date` to `Data` and back to `Date` check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502712/2303865

Comment: That is the correct time. 18:09:05+0100 is exactly the same point in time as 17:09:05+0000. Date represents a *point in time*. It has nothing to do with time zones. Time zones are printed in the debug output just for programmer convenience.

Comment: If you want to display a Date (a point in time) in some human-readable form, for example including time zones, then you need to use a DateFormatter to format it into a string (as you're doing). `print(date)` doesn't demonstrate anything about time zones; Dates don't have time zones.

Comment: @LeoDabus This gave me correct time; https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-convert-swift-dates-timezone - Is that any different then using ISO8601?

Comment: That’s ISO8601 but without fractional seconds

Answer (score 0):

DateFormatter converts in both directions. Using the same formatter, to convert it back, use `.date(from:)`

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

---

Based on your comments, you may be misunderstanding what a Date is. A Date is nothing more and nothing less than a number of seconds since the reference time. It doesn't know anything about time zones. It doesn't know anything about calendars. It doesn't even know anything about minutes or hours. It is *only* a number of seconds since the reference time (it is literally a small wrapper around a single Double value).

When you print a Date, it calls `.description`, and as a programmer convenience that is generated by a default DateFormatter that turns it into a human readable string purely for debugging purposes. That string does not imply that the Date has calendar or a time zone attached to it. It's just a programmer convenience. It should never be used by the program itself.

If you want to deal with time zones, you must use a Calendar to compute various DateComponents, or a DateFormatter (which uses a Calendar) to generate a String.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work? Please check my question for update.

Answer (score 0):

DateFormatter has an option to convert string to date as well:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:Z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
dateFormatter.date(from: yourStringDate)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work? Please check my question for update.